# How to fix "unable to create pristine install stream"

Tags: svn

Since about one or two weeks I get this error message and I don't know how to resolve it.

> Commit failed (details follow):
>
> Unable to create pristine install stream
>
> The system cannot find the path specified.

[image: SVN screenshot]

I neither know what a Pristine Install Stream is, nor does the message contain a hint about the path that is not found.

I've tried a `cleanup`, but the same error still occurs.

I [googled](https://www.google.de/search?q=%22Unable+to+create+pristine+install+stream%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=dXrkVqLqBYiU6ATygaTIDA#), but at the time of writing there are only 9 results available, some of them commit history of SVN changes, others unanswered question.

Comment: See bug report here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/tortoisesvn/4r_zm4-DBdU

Answer (score 142, accepted):

I dug into it with [Process Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processmonitor.aspx) and I found a line (one column per line below)

```
21:06:17,6337584    
TortoiseProc.exe    
14144   
CreateFile  
[...]\.svn\tmp\svn-4F235F40 
PATH NOT FOUND  
Desired Access: Generic Write, Read Attributes, Delete, 
Disposition: Create, 
Options: Synchronous IO Non-Alert, Non-Directory File, 
Attributes: N, 
ShareMode: None, 
AllocationSize: 0
```

Looking at my hard disk, I saw that there's no `tmp` folder inside my `.svn` folder.

Creating the `tmp` folder manually resolved the issue.

Comment: Is this a bug in svn?

Comment: @chrstphrchvz: I never figured out why that tmp folder can get lost. At least it would be a nice feature if SVN could auto-fix that missing folder issue, since it seems to happen quite often.

Comment: Interesting. I crossed the streams and nested SVN projects, and I was unable to commit but this turned out to be my issue as well -- I was able to commit my file changes after I manually created a tmp/ folder in the nested SVN project. Thanks!

Comment: In my case, tmp was empty when my backup program did the backup, so it didn't restore the directory. Thank you @ThomasWeller

Comment: Creating the tmp folder manually resolved the issue.This is work for me!Thank you very much...

Comment: This was the solution for me too.

Comment: Creating the missing tmp folder also resolved the error for me.

Answer (score 8):

On my system, the tmp folder was in the .svn directory.  So I did `rm -rf tmp` in the .svn directory.  Then `mkdir tmp` in the .svn directory and it fixed the problem.

Comment: I tried dropping and re-creating the tmp folder from command line and this didn't work, however in linux I am not the same user i am when i use svn in windows. I went into windows deleted and recreated the folder and that fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Create missing `...\.svn\tmp` directories recursive in the given `$path` with the following PowerShell script. If your directories are not hidden (usually they are), remove the `-Hidden` flag.

```
function CreateTmpDirInSvnRepos($path) 
{ 
Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse -Directory -Hidden | 
  Where-Object { $_.BaseName -match '.svn' } | 
    ForEach-Object { Join-Path -Path $_.FullName -ChildPath 'tmp' } |
      ForEach-Object { if (!(Test-Path $_)) { New-Item $_ -ItemType 'Directory' } }
}

CreateTmpDirInSvnRepos "C:\SVN"
```

My backup program ignored tmp folders, which is a common behavior I'd say. 
From my point of view SVN could fix it. If the directory doesn't exist create it. 
From SVN's point of view the statement would be "Don't touch my hidden files". 
Both points of view comprehensive. 
I think if SVN team would know about the issue they would create the tmp directory if missing. I'll put a request for them to do so. 

[EDIT] Just created the issue in apache SVN: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SVN-4868